# How does pytorch carry on the multiplication of two tensors that have different last dimensions?

Tags: pytorch

I'm having some difficulties understanding how this is done.
Imagine we have two tensors as follows:

```py
a = torch.arange(0,9).view(3,3)
b = torch.arange(0,30).view(2,3,5)
```

and want to calculate `a@b`.

The shapes don't match, so tensor `a` needs to be broadcasted and for that it first needs a batch dimension, so `a.unsqueeze(0)` is required followed by a replication operation along the `0th`'s dimension to resemble the tensor b, so `a = torch.cat(tuple(a.clone() for _ in range(2),dim=0)` handles that,
now we have two tensors one with (2,3,3) and the other with (2,3,5) as their shapes respectively.
How are we supposed to continue on now? the last dimensions are not the same, so no elementwise product here.

If we treat the first two dimensions (2,3) as batch dimension and get (6,3) and (6,5)
using transpose we can multiply these two tensors, but obviously, the shape will be (3,5) which is different than the (2,3,5) results Pytorch produces.

so how is the last part done?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of batch multiplication. if you look closely, you'll notice that, if you ignore the batch dimension, the rest of the dimensions are compatible, thus what remains is simply to multiply each sub-tensors individually.

```py
c = a@b 
# is equivalent to 
a = a.unsqueeze(0)
# replicate along the batch dimension
a = torch.cat(tuple(a.clone() for _ in range(2)),dim=0)
# now do batch-multiplication
c2 = torch.zeros_like(b)
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    c2[i,...] = a[i]@b[i]
print(f'c2==c:{torch.all(c2==c)}')
```